# Rails Application Thinks it's Production on Development Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails application on my laptop.  When I echo $RAILS_ENV it says "development".  When I log Rails.env in the app it says "production".  I don't think I'm setting anything to make that happen as when I deploy to my elastic beanstalk for staging it runs in the staging environment fine.

Has anyone seen this?

Comment: do you echo the env as the same user that runs the rails app?

Comment: If you have your repo in github/bitbucket and it's public, can you share with URL?

Comment: It's not public.  Let me try to echo the environment as that user and I'll report back.

Comment: sudo -u www echo $RAILS_ENV gives me development as well.  I'm assuming www is the user the app is running under.  That's my apache user and the app is running on apache and passenger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My vhost configuration was missing this in the directory section.

```
 RailsEnv development
```